# How to reset the billing address of a quote object?

Tags: php, magento, quote

I need to reset the billing address of a quote whenever the the customer comes to the one page checkout page.

So I extended the indexAction() method of the OnepageController and added following lines to create a new quote address object and assign it to the quote object. But debugging the code shows me that the address I get from the quote is still the old one.

```
...
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(false);
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_secure'=>true)));

$this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();

// --- Start of my code ------------------------------

// Create a new quote address object and pass it to the quote 
$newBillingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address');     
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setBillingAddress($newBillingAddress)->save();

// get address from quote to see whether is changed or not. 
// but it is still the old address.     
$billingAddress = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();

// --- End of my code ------------------------------

$this->loadLayout();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this issue and found out why it doesn't work as expected.

The reason is how the method for setting the address is implemented in the Quote class. Not the old address object gets replaced by the new one but the elements of the _data array of the new address get copied to the _data array of the old address.

As I created a new address object whose _data array is empty there where no items to copy to the old address's _data array so I always got the old data returned as the address object is still the old one.

Answer (score 0):

usually from my experience you can not perform a setter which is a in java world a void method (java is mention for comparison, i know u r in php land), and perform a save on it. Because you are not enacting on the object, but enacting on the function.

Have you try seperating out the setter, and then save?

```
$quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
$quote->setBillingAddress($newBillingAddress);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: Nope that's not the reason. Method chaining is a feature of Magento. Most methods return the instance of the class they belong to as a return argument. But of course I've tried it to be sure. ;)